How to render marker for each features gotten from vector tile API in Mapbox GL JS?
I am using Mapbox GL JS in my vuetify project. I have a vector tile API. This API will return points for each tile (xyz). I use addSource and addLayer to render the features gotten from the vector tile API. However, I am not satisfied with the default symbol rendered by the layers.
I want to add a marker for each features whenever the features are rendered. How can I do that?
One possible way is, I listen to the sourcedata event. There is a tile field in MapDataEvent. But I don't know how to get the features in the tile.
Following is my code:
map.on('sourcedata', (e) => {
    if (e.sourceId == 'my_source_id') {
        console.log('A sourcedata event occurred.');
        console.log(e);
        if (e.dataType == 'source' && e.tile) {
            // How can I get features in this tile?
        }
    }
});


I dont follow what you want...you just want different symbology when you are loading the layer?

What kind of features are there: polygons, lines, points?  Please edit your question with additional info.
